# Trying to bind marker with pop up message using leaflet JS programmatically

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

I'm currently building an Interactive Map using [leafletJS](https://leafletjs.com/) combined with `geocoder` and `map cluster` plugins. I'm trying to figure out how I can bind the pop up message programmatically. The element with the class `country-pop-up-message` is the content of the pop up message

```
<li  class="country">
    <span class="country-name">Philippines</span>
    <div class="country-pop-up-message">
        <h2 class="population">Population: 200</h2>
        <p class="description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>

    </div>
</li>
```

---

```
<ul class="countries">
    <li  class="country">
        <span class="country-name">Philippines</span>
        <div class="country-pop-up-message">
            <h2 class="population">Population: 200</h2>
            <p class="description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>

        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="country">
        <span class="country-name">Brunei</span>
        <div class="country-pop-up-message">
            <h2 class="population">Population: 200</h2>
            <p class="description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>

        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="country">
        <span class="country-name">Malaysia</span>
        <div class="country-pop-up-message">
            <h2 class="population">Population: 300</h2>
            <p class="description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>

        </div>
    </li>

</ul>
```

Below is the code that I've been working on in building the feature. The script below is a combination of leaflet `geocoder` and `map cluster` plugin. This is to plot the location with only the country name and cluster them together of plots that are next to each other.

```
    geocoder = new L.Control.Geocoder.Nominatim();

    var countries = [];
    var markers = [];

    var markerCluster = L.markerClusterGroup({ 
        spiderfyOnMaxZoom: false, 
        showCoverageOnHover: false,
        // zoomToBoundsOnClick: false 
    });



    $('.countries > .country > .country-name').each(function() {
        countries.push([
            $(this).text()                
        ]);
    });



    for(var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {

        geocoder.geocode(countries[i], function(results) {   
            console.log(countries[i]); 
            var latLng = new L.LatLng(results[0].center.lat, results[0].center.lng);
            marker = L.marker(latLng);


            markers.push(marker);
            markerCluster.addLayer(marker);
        });
    }

    markerCluster.on('clusterclick', function (a) {
    });
    map.addLayer(markerCluster);
```

```js
        var map = L.map('mapid', {

            fullscreenControl: {
                pseudoFullscreen: false // if true, fullscreen to page width and height
            },
            
        }).setView([0,0], 3);

        map.createPane('labels');
        map.getPane('labels').style.zIndex = 650;
        map.getPane('labels').style.pointerEvents = 'none';

        var positron = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                noWrap: true,
                maxZoom : 15
        }).addTo(map);

        var positronLabels = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_only_labels/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                pane: 'labels',
                noWrap: true,
                maxZoom : 3
        }).addTo(map);


        var southWest = L.latLng(-89.98155760646617, -180),
            northEast = L.latLng(89.99346179538875, 180),
            bounds = L.latLngBounds(southWest, northEast);

        map.setMaxBounds(bounds);
        map.on('drag', function() {
            map.panInsideBounds(bounds, { animate: false });
        });


        geocoder = new L.Control.Geocoder.Nominatim();

        var countries = [];
        var markers = [];

        var markerCluster = L.markerClusterGroup({ 
            spiderfyOnMaxZoom: false, 
            showCoverageOnHover: false,
            // zoomToBoundsOnClick: false 
        });



        $('.countries > .country > .country-name').each(function() {
            countries.push([
                $(this).text()                
            ]);
        });

    

        for(var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
            
            geocoder.geocode(countries[i], function(results) {   
                console.log(countries[i]); 
                var latLng = new L.LatLng(results[0].center.lat, results[0].center.lng);
                marker = L.marker(latLng);

  
                markers.push(marker);
                markerCluster.addLayer(marker);
            });
        }

        markerCluster.on('clusterclick', function (a) {
        });
        map.addLayer(markerCluster);
```

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}

/* required styles */

.leaflet-pane,
.leaflet-tile,
.leaflet-marker-icon,
.leaflet-marker-shadow,
.leaflet-tile-container,
.leaflet-pane > svg,
.leaflet-pane > canvas,
.leaflet-zoom-box,
.leaflet-image-layer,
.leaflet-layer {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 }
.leaflet-container {
 overflow: hidden;
 }
.leaflet-tile,
.leaflet-marker-icon,
.leaflet-marker-shadow {
 -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
         user-select: none;
   -webkit-user-drag: none;
 }
/* Safari renders non-retina tile on retina better with this, but Chrome is worse */
.leaflet-safari .leaflet-tile {
 image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;
 }
/* hack that prevents hw layers "stretching" when loading new tiles */
.leaflet-safari .leaflet-tile-container {
 width: 1600px;
 height: 1600px;
 -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
 }
.leaflet-marker-icon,
.leaflet-marker-shadow {
 display: block;
 }
/* .leaflet-container svg: reset svg max-width decleration shipped in Joomla! (joomla.org) 3.x */
/* .leaflet-container img: map is broken in FF if you have max-width: 100% on tiles */
.leaflet-container .leaflet-overlay-pane svg,
.leaflet-container .leaflet-marker-pane img,
.leaflet-container .leaflet-shadow-pane img,
.leaflet-container .leaflet-tile-pane img,
.leaflet-container img.leaflet-image-layer,
.leaflet-container .leaflet-tile {
 max-width: none !important;
 max-height: none !important;
 }

.leaflet-container.leaflet-touch-zoom {
 -ms-touch-action: pan-x pan-y;
 touch-action: pan-x pan-y;
 }
.leaflet-container.leaflet-touch-drag {
 -ms-touch-action: pinch-zoom;
 /* Fallback for FF which doesn't support pinch-zoom */
 touch-action: none;
 touch-action: pinch-zoom;
}
.leaflet-container.leaflet-touch-drag.leaflet-touch-zoom {
 -ms-touch-action: none;
 touch-action: none;
}
.leaflet-container {
 -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
.leaflet-container a {
 -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(51, 181, 229, 0.4);
}
.leaflet-tile {
 filter: inherit;
 visibility: hidden;
 }
.leaflet-tile-loaded {
 visibility: inherit;
 }
.leaflet-zoom-box {
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
 z-index: 800;
 }
/* workaround for https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=888319 */
.leaflet-overlay-pane svg {
 -moz-user-select: none;
 }

.leaflet-pane         { z-index: 400; }

.leaflet-tile-pane    { z-index: 200; }
.leaflet-overlay-pane { z-index: 400; }
.leaflet-shadow-pane  { z-index: 500; }
.leaflet-marker-pane  { z-index: 600; }
.leaflet-tooltip-pane   { z-index: 650; }
.leaflet-popup-pane   { z-index: 700; }

.leaflet-map-pane canvas { z-index: 100; }
.leaflet-map-pane svg    { z-index: 200; }

.leaflet-vml-shape {
 width: 1px;
 height: 1px;
 }
.lvml {
 behavior: url(#default#VML);
 display: inline-block;
 position: absolute;
 }


/* control positioning */

.leaflet-control {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 800;
 pointer-events: visiblePainted; /* IE 9-10 doesn't have auto */
 pointer-events: auto;
 }
.leaflet-top,
.leaflet-bottom {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1000;
 pointer-events: none;
 }
.leaflet-top {
 top: 0;
 }
.leaflet-right {
 right: 0;
 }
.leaflet-bottom {
 bottom: 0;
 }
.leaflet-left {
 left: 0;
 }
.leaflet-control {
 float: left;
 clear: both;
 }
.leaflet-right .leaflet-control {
 float: right;
 }
.leaflet-top .leaflet-control {
 margin-top: 10px;
 }
.leaflet-bottom .leaflet-control {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 }
.leaflet-left .leaflet-control {
 margin-left: 10px;
 }
.leaflet-right .leaflet-control {
 margin-right: 10px;
 }


/* zoom and fade animations */

.leaflet-fade-anim .leaflet-tile {
 will-change: opacity;
 }
.leaflet-fade-anim .leaflet-popup {
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
         transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
 }
.leaflet-fade-anim .leaflet-map-pane .leaflet-popup {
 opacity: 1;
 }
.leaflet-zoom-animated {
 -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
     -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
         transform-origin: 0 0;
 }
.leaflet-zoom-anim .leaflet-zoom-animated {
 will-change: transform;
 }
.leaflet-zoom-anim .leaflet-zoom-animated {
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.25s cubic-bezier(0,0,0.25,1);
    -moz-transition:    -moz-transform 0.25s cubic-bezier(0,0,0.25,1);
         transition:         transform 0.25s cubic-bezier(0,0,0.25,1);
 }
.leaflet-zoom-anim .leaflet-tile,
.leaflet-pan-anim .leaflet-tile {
 -webkit-transition: none;
    -moz-transition: none;
         transition: none;
 }

.leaflet-zoom-anim .leaflet-zoom-hide {
 visibility: hidden;
 }


/* cursors */

.leaflet-interactive {
 cursor: pointer;
 }
.leaflet-grab {
 cursor: -webkit-grab;
 cursor:    -moz-grab;
 cursor:         grab;
 }
.leaflet-crosshair,
.leaflet-crosshair .leaflet-interactive {
 cursor: crosshair;
 }
.leaflet-popup-pane,
.leaflet-control {
 cursor: auto;
 }
.leaflet-dragging .leaflet-grab,
.leaflet-dragging .leaflet-grab .leaflet-interactive,
.leaflet-dragging .leaflet-marker-draggable {
 cursor: move;
 cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
 cursor:    -moz-grabbing;
 cursor:         grabbing;
 }

/* marker & overlays interactivity */
.leaflet-marker-icon,
.leaflet-marker-shadow,
.leaflet-image-layer,
.leaflet-pane > svg path,
.leaflet-tile-container {
 pointer-events: none;
 }

.leaflet-marker-icon.leaflet-interactive,
.leaflet-image-layer.leaflet-interactive,
.leaflet-pane > svg path.leaflet-interactive {
 pointer-events: visiblePainted; /* IE 9-10 doesn't have auto */
 pointer-events: auto;
 }

/* visual tweaks */

.leaflet-container {
 background: #ddd;
 outline: 0;
 }
.leaflet-container a {
 color: #0078A8;
 }
.leaflet-container a.leaflet-active {
 outline: 2px solid orange;
 }
.leaflet-zoom-box {
 border: 2px dotted #38f;
 background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
 }


/* general typography */
.leaflet-container {
 font: 12px/1.5 "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 }


/* general toolbar styles */

.leaflet-bar {
 box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
 border-radius: 4px;
 }
.leaflet-bar a,
.leaflet-bar a:hover {
 background-color: #fff;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
 width: 26px;
 height: 26px;
 line-height: 26px;
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
 }
.leaflet-bar a,
.leaflet-control-layers-toggle {
 background-position: 50% 50%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 display: block;
 }
.leaflet-bar a:hover {
 background-color: #f4f4f4;
 }
.leaflet-bar a:first-child {
 border-top-left-radius: 4px;
 border-top-right-radius: 4px;
 }
.leaflet-bar a:last-child {
 border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
 border-bottom: none;
 }
.leaflet-bar a.leaflet-disabled {
 cursor: default;
 background-color: #f4f4f4;
 color: #bbb;
 }

.leaflet-touch .leaflet-bar a {
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 line-height: 30px;
 }
.leaflet-touch .leaflet-bar a:first-child {
 border-top-left-radius: 2px;
 border-top-right-radius: 2px;
 }
.leaflet-touch .leaflet-bar a:last-child {
 border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
 }

/* zoom control */

.leaflet-control-zoom-in,
.leaflet-control-zoom-out {
 font: bold 18px 'Lucida Console', Monaco, monospace;
 text-indent: 1px;
 }

.leaflet-touch .leaflet-control-zoom-in, .leaflet-touch .leaflet-control-zoom-out  {
 font-size: 22px;
 }


/* layers control */

.leaflet-control-layers {
 box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
 background: #fff;
 border-radius: 5px;
 }
.leaflet-control-layers-toggle {
 background-image: url(images/layers.png);
 width: 36px;
 height: 36px;
 }
.leaflet-retina .leaflet-control-layers-toggle {
 background-image: url(images/layers-2x.png);
 background-size: 26px 26px;
 }
.leaflet-touch .leaflet-control-layers-toggle {
 width: 44px;
 height: 44px;
 }
.leaflet-control-layers .leaflet-control-layers-list,
.leaflet-control-layers-expanded .leaflet-control-layers-toggle {
 display: none;
 }
.leaflet-control-layers-expanded .leaflet-control-layers-list {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 }
.leaflet-control-layers-expanded {
 padding: 6px 10px 6px 6px;
 color: #333;
 background: #fff;
 }
.leaflet-control-layers-scrollbar {
 overflow-y: scroll;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 padding-right: 5px;
 }
.leaflet-control-layers-selector {
 margin-top: 2px;
 position: relative;
 top: 1px;
 }
.leaflet-control-layers label {
 display: block;
 }
.leaflet-control-layers-separator {
 height: 0;
 border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
 margin: 5px -10px 5px -6px;
 }

/* Default icon URLs */
.leaflet-default-icon-path {
 background-image: url(images/marker-icon.png);
 }


/* attribution and scale controls */

.leaflet-container .leaflet-control-attribution {
 background: #fff;
 background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
 margin: 0;
 }
.leaflet-control-attribution,
.leaflet-control-scale-line {
 padding: 0 5px;
 color: #333;
 }
.leaflet-control-attribution a {
 text-decoration: none;
 }
.leaflet-control-attribution a:hover {
 text-decoration: underline;
 }
.leaflet-container .leaflet-control-attribution,
.leaflet-container .leaflet-control-scale {
 font-size: 11px;
 }
.leaflet-left .leaflet-control-scale {
 margin-left: 5px;
 }
.leaflet-bottom .leaflet-control-scale {
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 }
.leaflet-control-scale-line {
 border: 2px solid #777;
 border-top: none;
 line-height: 1.1;
 padding: 2px 5px 1px;
 font-size: 11px;
 white-space: nowrap;
 overflow: hidden;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;

 background: #fff;
 background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
 }
.leaflet-control-scale-line:not(:first-child) {
 border-top: 2px solid #777;
 border-bottom: none;
 margin-top: -2px;
 }
.leaflet-control-scale-line:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
 border-bottom: 2px solid #777;
 }

.leaflet-touch .leaflet-control-attribution,
.leaflet-touch .leaflet-control-layers,
.leaflet-touch .leaflet-bar {
 box-shadow: none;
 }
.leaflet-touch .leaflet-control-layers,
.leaflet-touch .leaflet-bar {
 border: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 background-clip: padding-box;
 }


/* popup */

.leaflet-popup {
 position: absolute;
 text-align: center;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 }
.leaflet-popup-content-wrapper {
 padding: 1px;
 text-align: left;
 border-radius: 12px;
 }
.leaflet-popup-content {
 margin: 13px 19px;
 line-height: 1.4;
 }
.leaflet-popup-content p {
 margin: 18px 0;
 }
.leaflet-popup-tip-container {
 width: 40px;
 height: 20px;
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -20px;
 overflow: hidden;
 pointer-events: none;
 }
.leaflet-popup-tip {
 width: 17px;
 height: 17px;
 padding: 1px;

 margin: -10px auto 0;

 -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
     -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
         transform: rotate(45deg);
 }
.leaflet-popup-content-wrapper,
.leaflet-popup-tip {
 background: white;
 color: #333;
 box-shadow: 0 3px 14px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
 }
.leaflet-container a.leaflet-popup-close-button {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 padding: 4px 4px 0 0;
 border: none;
 text-align: center;
 width: 18px;
 height: 14px;
 font: 16px/14px Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
 color: #c3c3c3;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: bold;
 background: transparent;
 }
.leaflet-container a.leaflet-popup-close-button:hover {
 color: #999;
 }
.leaflet-popup-scrolled {
 overflow: auto;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
 border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
 }

.leaflet-oldie .leaflet-popup-content-wrapper {
 zoom: 1;
 }
.leaflet-oldie .leaflet-popup-tip {
 width: 24px;
 margin: 0 auto;

 -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.70710678, M12=0.70710678, M21=-0.70710678, M22=0.70710678)";
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.70710678, M12=0.70710678, M21=-0.70710678, M22=0.70710678);
 }
.leaflet-oldie .leaflet-popup-tip-container {
 margin-top: -1px;
 }

.leaflet-oldie .leaflet-control-zoom,
.leaflet-oldie .leaflet-control-layers,
.leaflet-oldie .leaflet-popup-content-wrapper,
.leaflet-oldie .leaflet-popup-tip {
 border: 1px solid #999;
 }


/* div icon */

.leaflet-div-icon {
 background: #fff;
 border: 1px solid #666;
 }


/* Tooltip */
/* Base styles for the element that has a tooltip */
.leaflet-tooltip {
 position: absolute;
 padding: 6px;
 background-color: #fff;
 border: 1px solid #fff;
 border-radius: 3px;
 color: #222;
 white-space: nowrap;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
 pointer-events: none;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
 }
.leaflet-tooltip.leaflet-clickable {
 cursor: pointer;
 pointer-events: auto;
 }
.leaflet-tooltip-top:before,
.leaflet-tooltip-bottom:before,
.leaflet-tooltip-left:before,
.leaflet-tooltip-right:before {
 position: absolute;
 pointer-events: none;
 border: 6px solid transparent;
 background: transparent;
 content: "";
 }

/* Directions */

.leaflet-tooltip-bottom {
 margin-top: 6px;
}
.leaflet-tooltip-top {
 margin-top: -6px;
}
.leaflet-tooltip-bottom:before,
.leaflet-tooltip-top:before {
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -6px;
 }
.leaflet-tooltip-top:before {
 bottom: 0;
 margin-bottom: -12px;
 border-top-color: #fff;
 }
.leaflet-tooltip-bottom:before {
 top: 0;
 margin-top: -12px;
 margin-left: -6px;
 border-bottom-color: #fff;
 }
.leaflet-tooltip-left {
 margin-left: -6px;
}
.leaflet-tooltip-right {
 margin-left: 6px;
}
.leaflet-tooltip-left:before,
.leaflet-tooltip-right:before {
 top: 50%;
 margin-top: -6px;
 }
.leaflet-tooltip-left:before {
 right: 0;
 margin-right: -12px;
 border-left-color: #fff;
 }
.leaflet-tooltip-right:before {
 left: 0;
 margin-left: -12px;
 border-right-color: #fff;
 }



html, body {
    width  : 100%;
    height : 100%;
}

.map-container {
    width : 100%;
    height : 100%;
    
}
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.css"
  />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.4.1/dist/MarkerCluster.Default.css" />

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.js"
    ></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBet5Wx-JdSc4cY4v4zR6_FIhYc2oWgTv4"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-control-geocoder/dist/Control.Geocoder.js" ></script>
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/leaflet.gridlayer.googlemutant@latest/Leaflet.GoogleMutant.js'></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.4.1/dist/leaflet.markercluster-src.js"></script>
    
    <div class="map-container" id="mapid"></div>
    
            <ul class="countries">
            <li  class="country">
                <span class="country-name">Philippines</span>
                <div class="country-pop-up-message">
                    <h2 class="population">Population: 200</h2>
                    <p class="description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>

                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="country">
                <span class="country-name">Brunei</span>
                <div class="country-pop-up-message">
                    <h2 class="population">Population: 200</h2>
                    <p class="description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>

                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="country">
                <span class="country-name">Malaysia</span>
                <div class="country-pop-up-message">
                    <h2 class="population">Population: 300</h2>
                    <p class="description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>

                </div>
            </li>

        </ul>
```

Comment: Hello, what do you mean for "bind up the pop up programatically" what is the expected output of this? This clarification could drive more help here

Comment: @SirPeople Basically what I'm trying to do aside from displaying the marker, I also wanted to display the pop up message as well.

Comment: @SirPeople How can I bind the marker along with the pop up message or to clarify how can I display the marker along with the pop up message

Comment: Ah, thank you, much more clear. Hopefully I (or anybody) can give you an answer soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, let me try to give you an answer to this problem.

So basically you want to bind an existing DOM element to a marker that is added through JS.

Well, I imagine that with your current "solution" you are facing some difficulties.

- It is **difficult to find a specific pop up**. You need to first scrap the DOM and then compare the name in country-names.
- You have the **pop up and the JS code "far" from each other**, and for far I mean that in your JS code do not even know which countries are in the HTML.

**Proposed alternative**

Why don't you also generate this pop ups programmatically? You could have your countries with the next shape:

```
const countries = {
  {name: "Malaysia", population: 200, description: "Blablabla"},
  {name: "Philipines", population: 300, description: "Tatatata"},
  ...
}
```

then to generate the DOM elements for each country should be as easy as:

```
function createPopUp(country) {
    const countryWrapper = document.createElement('li');
    countryWrapper.className = 'country';

    const countryName = document.createElement('span');
    countryName.className = 'country-name';
    countryName.id = country.name;
    countryName.append(country.name);

    const countryInfo = document.createElement('div');
    countryInfo.className = 'country-pop-up-message';

    const population = document.createElement('h2');
    population.className = 'population';
    population.append(`Population: ${country.population}`);

    const description = document.createElement('p');
    description.className = 'description';
    description.append(country.description);

    countryInfo.appendChild(population);
    countryInfo.appendChild(description);

    countryWrapper.appendChild(countryName);
    countryWrapper.appendChild(countryInfo);

    return countryWrapper;
}
```

Then from here it is very simple!

Leaflet have an easy way of adding Popups `.bindPopup(content).openPopup()`

So then you just need to modify your code to accept the new way of giving countries, [take a look in the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3y2g96ku/1/). I tried to edit as little as possible.

Hopefully this works :D

Comment: By the way why not use `jquery` instead of `vanilla javascript` for the function `createPopUp`? I might have to just loop this part `const countries = {
  {name: "Malaysia", population: 200, description: "Blablabla"},
  {name: "Philipines", population: 300, description: "Tatatata"},
  ...
}` to fetch the contents in the `DOM` instead of declaring it manually

Comment: I did it in VanillaJS for the shake of not depending on jQuery, but it should be same kind of process. And yes, if you use the createPopUp you do not need to declare anything in the html side

Comment: Apologies for my ignorance this a javascript object right? `{name: "Malaysia", population: 200, description: "Blablabla"}`

Comment: No problem. Yes, brackets in JS indicate that it is an object. Ask any question and once it is solved, please mark the question as answered

Comment: Hey, I've marked your solution as an answer to my question. Would it be ok if I ask to convert the `vanillaJS` to `jQuery` instead if you don't mind since I would rather much prefer to be in `jQuery`